# ViewBag data doesn't exists when Rendering Partial View in asp.net core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Into a asp.net core 1.0 (Full Framework 4.6.1), I needed to render a partial view to string, so based on https://gist.github.com/ahmad-moussawi/1643d703c11699a6a4046e57247b4d09, I created a RenderView:

```
public class ViewRender
{
    private IRazorViewEngine _viewEngine;
    private ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ViewRender(
        IRazorViewEngine viewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public string Render<TModel>(string view, TModel model)
    {
        var actionContext = GetActionContext();

        var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, view, false);

        if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Couldn't find view '{0}'", view));
        }

        var viewResult = viewEngineResult.View;

        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                viewResult,
                new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                    metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                },
                new TempDataDictionary(
                    actionContext.HttpContext,
                    _tempDataProvider),
                output,
                new HtmlHelperOptions());

            viewContext.Vi
            viewResult.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private ActionContext GetActionContext()
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
        httpContext.RequestServices = _serviceProvider;
        return new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
    }
}
```

however when Controller call the PartialView:

```
string render = _viewRender.Render("Directory/_DirectoryData", directory);
```

Data set into ViewBag Controller previously as follows.

```
ViewBag.ParticipantTypesList = _dbInstance.ParticipantTypes;
ViewBag.DirectoryList = _dbInstance.Directories;
ViewBag.TaxCategoryList = _dbInstance.TaxCategories;
```

Doesn't exists when using them for combobox ítems:

```
<label asp-for="DirectoryItem_DirectoryItem" class="form-control-label"></label>
<select asp-for="DirectoryItem_DirectoryItem" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.DirectoryList, "Id", "DirectoryId", null))" class="form-control">
  <option>--- Seleccione ---</option>
</select>
```

And Render throws an exception. Please help me how to get or transfer ViewBag.

¿I have to use _viewEngine.FindView(...) or _viewEngine.FindPage(...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've found answer by myself!

I not need to render partial view to a string which was causing me a headache. Just using return PartialView into Controller returns a string to the ajax function caller in javascript and therefore ViewBag variables can be accessed without problems into cshtml partial view.